# Rackmount chassis for Alix2d3

Tags: hardware

- What rackmount chassis are available for the [Alix2d3](http://www.pcengines.ch/alix2d3.htm)?
- Can the [Alix2d3](http://www.pcengines.ch/alix2d3.htm), which is described as a 6"x6" board, fit in an enclosure designed for miniITX boards, which is the form factor of the [Alix1d](http://www.pcengines.ch/alix1d.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following rackmount chasses options for the Alix2d3:

- [Varia 19" DualRack System for MikroTik and PC Engines ALIX boards, item 311624](http://shop.varia-store.com/product_info.php?info=p694_19---DualRack-System-for-MikroTik-and-PC-Engines-ALIX-boards.html)
- [LinITX ALIX Rackmount Chassis](http://linitx.com/viewproduct.php?prodid=12745)
- [Yawarra Dual board rack mount server case](http://www.yawarra.com.au/en-rack.php)